# How to deal with damaged cards from a MTG booster pack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I bought a Magic the Gathering display box today with cards from the new edition Innistrad. Unfortunately one of the cards in a booster pack was damaged. It is not just a simple scratch - one corner is bent and a small part of the card is missing. According to different trading platforms this card would be worth about 6 Dollars minimum in mint condition. So it is not really expensive but also not totally worthless.

What can I do about this? Can I obtain a replacement card from the producer (WotC) or from the store I bought it from? How can I prove that the card was damaged when I opened the booster pack? I am sure I am not the first person who got a damaged card from a booster pack. How are such issues usually handled?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wizards of the Coast has a process you can follow for the replacement of defective products purchased, described in detail [on their website](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10/~/replacing-defective-magic%3a-the-gathering-products):

> If you purchase a product and find that only one or several cards are damaged, defective, or missing when you open it, please return any damaged cards (if not missing), and follow the shipping guidelines provided above.  We'll replace the exact cards for you.